# Using require_once() within admin

Tags: admin

In my theme directory I have the following structure:

/includes/functions-custom.php
/includes/avatax/AvaTax.php
/includes/classes/gmaps.class.php

I'm making a call from the functions-custom.php to include the second file within the WordPress admin using this code

```
require_once('avatax/AvaTax.php'); //Avalara Sales Tax API
if ( is_admin() ) {
    require_once('classes/gmaps.class.php');
}
```

The first require applies to both the theme and to the admin. The second, obviously, only applies to the admin. However, the first require fails with the following message:

```
Warning: require_once(/Users/philipdowner/Sites/dms/wp-content/themes/dms/includes/avatax/classes/BatchSvc/WP_User_Search.class.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/philipdowner/Sites/dms/wp-content/themes/dms/includes/avatax/AvaTax.php on line 23

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/Users/philipdowner/Sites/dms/wp-content/themes/dms/includes/avatax/classes/BatchSvc/WP_User_Search.class.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php') in /Users/philipdowner/Sites/dms/wp-content/themes/dms/includes/avatax/AvaTax.php on line 23
```

I don't feel like this should be such a stumper. Perhaps I'm overlooking something obvious? I've tried preceding the file path with the constant 'TEMPLATEPATH' and using the obvious WordPress functions like

```
require_once(get_template_directory().'/path/to/file');
```

I'm developing locally on MAMP. Particularly odd is the call to the file (in the error message) '/classes/BatchSvc/WP_User_Search.class.php'.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I marked the appropriate solution.

Comment: Missed that completely, as it stays on bottom. Btw: You have PHP 5.3+, right?

Comment: Any progress on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a night of sleep, and confirmation from the above users that I was including files properly, I've managed to resolve the issue.

In the AvaTax.php file, there was an __autoload() function:

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) 
{   

if ( $class_name != 'WP_User_Search' ) { //WORDPRESS HACK
    $path=dirname(__FILE__).'/classes/'.$class_name . '.class.php';

    if(!file_exists($path))
    {
        $path=dirname(__FILE__).'/classes/BatchSvc/'.$class_name . '.class.php';

    }

    require_once $path;
}


}
?>
```

The function is being passed a variable from WordPress - $class_name. I'm not entirely sure where the variable comes from, but could probably dump the $_GLOBALS or $wp_query and find out. I've basically ensured (hacked) the function to ensure that the variable passed doesn't match the string 'WP_User_Search'.

As for my include files I've used the following code:

```
<?php
define('INCLUDE_PATH', get_template_directory().'/includes');
require_once(INCLUDE_PATH.'/avatax/AvaTax.php'); //Avalara Sales Tax API
if ( is_admin() ) {
require_once(INCLUDE_PATH.'/classes/gmaps.class.php');
}
?>
```

Thanks for helping me work thru this one guys!

Comment: So it's only for parent themes?

Comment: I like to get in the habit of prefixing stuff. Functions, Classes, Globals, Constants, etc. Just in-case somewhere else is defining the same thing. Maybe change `INCLUDE_PATH` to something like `PREFIX_INCLUDE_PATH`.

Answer (score 12):

### Avoid native php functions

1. They are not relative, so breaking stuff is easy. (like in the OPs case)
2. Why role your own if core got a function for you?
3. They don't consider edge cases

You should NEVER use the constants

- `STYLESHEET_DIRECTORY`
- `TEMPLATE_DIRECTORY`
- `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`
- etc...

<sup>Remember: Those are *not* API! and can therefore change!</sup>

*but* INSTEAD USE the following API functions:

- Parent Theme: `get_template_directory()` / `get_template_directory_uri()`
- Child Theme: `get_stylesheet_directory()` / `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`

You can use both in Plugins and Themes:

- `plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/your/path/to/file.ext` <sup>*) for Themes also</sup>
- `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'/your/path/to/file.ext`

but `plugin_dir_url()` is reserved *only* for Plugins.

### Keep in mind...

That there're

- Plugins
- MU-Plugins
- Drop-Ins
- Themes
- Themes in directories registered via `register_theme_directory( $dir );`

So please stick with the native API functions like `wp_upload_dir();`, `content_url();`, etc.

In general: Take a look at `/wp-includes/link-template.php` for a whole bunch of nice path and URl related API functions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the require is being called from within `AvaTax.php`, so if you change the call to `../classes/gmaps.class.php` (in `AvaTax.php`, not in `functions-custom.php`) it should fix the error.

Comment: I think this is closer to the root problem. Try including `get_template_directory()` in **all** uses of `require()` or `include()`, so as to avoid relative-path problems such as this one.

Answer (score 0):

[Manifestphil](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/947/manifestphil), if you use WordPress Autoloader, you don't have to worry about loading files of classes. Of course you have to write clean class files on this case, which also makes your code more manageable.

Easy steps:

- Create folder /lib inside your theme root folder
- To avoid problems with same class names, use **namespaces** and create **appropriate folders structure**
- Write your code wisely to support classes autoload. Divide code into classes, so that classes are loaded only when absolutely necessary. Avoid big class files.

For example to load class MyNameSpace\MyClass you need folders structure shown below:

```
/mytheme
   /lib
      /MyNameSpace
         /MyClass.php
```

If you initialize new object or call some method etc, your class file is automatically loaded. Also it works really fine with any WordPress hooking method, for example:

```
add_action ( 'admin_menu', 'MyNameSpace\MyClass::AddSomeToolsMenu' );
```

On case above your class is loaded only when actually needed and called by WordPress :)

Comment: You can user WordPress Autoloader plugin: - https://bitbucket.org/holyfield/wp-autoloader